# list indices must be integers or slices, not str but in another code this error don't happened

Tags: python, list, dictionary

i want to run this code

```
listf = [
    {"name":"akram"}
]
for i in listf:
    print(listf["name"])
```

and this eroor happend

```
line 5, in <module>
    print(listf["name"])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

but in another code from another user :

```
students = [
    {"name": "Hermione", "house": "Gryffindor", "patronus": "Otter"},
    {"name": "Harry", "house": "Gryffindor", "patronus": "Stag"},
    {"name": "Ron", "house": "Gryffindor", "patronus": "Jack Russell terrier"},
    {"name": "Draco", "house": "Slytherin", "patronus": None},
]

for student in students:
    print(student["name"], student["house"], student["patronus"], sep=", ")
```

and it run normal with the output :

```
Hermione, Gryffindor, Otter
Harry, Gryffindor, Stag
Ron, Gryffindor, Jack Russell terrier
Draco, Slytherin, None
```

Comment: `listf` is a list, it's indexed via integers: 0. 1... You can iterate through it like in the second case & access the each dictionary inside the list with string keys. The 2 cases are not the same.

Comment: The variable name is incorrect. It should be `i['name']` instead of `listf['name']`.

Comment: oh i get it now thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the second example they accessed `students` dictionaries via `student` not `students`. Let me show it to you differently:

```
for st in students: # Here I changed student by st
    print(st["name"], st["house"], st["patronus"], sep=", ")
```

Try this will help you make the distinction in your code:

```
listf = [
    {"name":"akram"}
]
for i in listf:
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
{"name":"akram"}
```

See? Here `i` is the dictionary. Here's how you should access it:

```
listf = [
    {"name":"akram"}
]
for i in listf:
    print(i["name"])
```